# Design a circuit using 1 ideal op amp whose output is Vo = VI1 + 2Vi2 - 9VI3 + 4Vi4

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, circuit-design, inverting-amplifier, non-inverting

So, I've been staring at this problem for several hours now. I've watched videos on summing amplifiers, and the like--but nothing seems to show how to use 1 op amp in a circuit that acts as both a non-inverting and an inverting amplifier...I've seen the math behind this and it looks absolutely insane, so I'm trying to make intuitive sense of it.

Here's the problem statement:
[image]

Here's the referenced figure:

[image]

And here's the circuit that the Chegg solution starts from:
[image]

And I've been trying to make intuitive sense of it using the basic op-amp configurations to break it down into parts:

[image]

So, what I've been thinking is that there is some ratios between the resistors that gives the coefficients of the respective inputs, with the input at the negative op-amp terminal being the "-9VI3" component...but I haven't gotten anywhere further with it. :/

So, if anyone could help me wrap my mind around the logical process of solving and interpreting these kinds of problems, I'd be extremely grateful! I don't want to have to just memorize the 3-page algebra process to solve a problem like this...

Comment: "I've watched videos on summing amplifiers" I take they have banned and burned all books where you are, closed all the libraries, and removed the knowledge of how to read from your brain?   Videos.  I'm going go have a drink in remembrance of learning, and cry over the future of science and technology.

Comment: I don’t learn well from books—certainly not these topics. Ulaby Signals & Systems, Sedra/Smith Microelectronics, are not that helpful to me.

Comment: You should figure out how you can learn from books. You can rely on youtube videos or internet fora forever.

Comment: I never saw such assignment in my textbooks either, so, I wonder if it has to do with books or videos. It's true posting crap on internet is cheaper than have it printed, but are we discussing this here?

Comment: @CalebH Can you *reason/calculate* what you're doing when applying an Inverting Summing Amplifier? Can you obtain the same equation for Vout using the OpAmp golden rules? Using that, you should be able to find a general equation for P2.47 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Lets begin by looking at the "-9VI3" component. This requires an inverted amplification with a gain of 9 (or you can also say an amplification with a gain of -9). Notice how both the Inverting amp and the non inverting amp both share feedback resistor R2 going from output to inverting input.

[image: Figure 1. Inverting amplifier diagram]

To achieve -Vout, you would need Vin * 9. Such a combination of resistors could be 1800 Ohm / 200 Ohm. Don't be confused by the diagram stating -Vin as the only input condition. You can input anything you like, as long as the op-amp can reach that voltage from the supplies. Just remember that the inverting amplifier will give you an inverted output.

For the other inputs, you now have a value for R2 to calculate from.

Example: VI1 requires no amplification, and should be summed as it is, so use a gain of 1. This would mean R1 must equal R2+1, or 1801 Ohms. This is not a ["real" resistor value](http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/data/resistor/e-series-e3-e6-e12-e24-e48-e96.php) but you could construct this from series resistors.

Continuing, VI2 and VI4 are require a gain of 2 and 4 respectively, so use an R1 value for each that would give those gains.

Comment: So, say I choose 1.8k for my feedback resistor. Then for VI1, wouldn't that give: Gain = 1 = 1 + (1800/R1)? And no solutions exist for R1 in that equation?

Comment: I think you are looking at the formula strangely. The *gain must equal 1*, so Vout = Vin x 1 must be the sum. Therefore, 1 + R2 must equal R1. Example: 1800ohm is chosen for R2, then R1 must be 1801ohm (1.8k + 1ohm)

Comment: Where are you getting the formula 1 + R2 = R1?

Comment: That is the formula for the non-inverting amplifier

Comment: Is that the same as: V_out = V_in * (1 + R2/R1)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the principle of superposition. If you set all the non-inverting inputs to zero, then then single inverting input implies a gain of -9, so you might arbitrarily pick 90K for a feedback resistor, meaning your Rn1 must be 90K/9 = 10K.

Turning our attention to the non-inverting inputs, it's clear that the gain from the non-inverting input of the op-amp will be 9+1 = 10.

So we need to come up with a voltage divider that has ratios of 10:1, 5:1 and 5:2 to get the desired overall gains.

We know that the output of a voltage divider with n input resistors is:

Vout = (V1/R1+V2/R2+..+Vn/Rn)*(R1||R2||..||Rn||Rp0) where Rp0 is the resistor to ground and Ri are the input resistors.

To match the input resistances seen at the inputs (technically unnecessary since it's an ideal op-amp but it quashes one degree of freedom) we want (R1||R2||..||Rn||Rp0) = 10K||90K = 9K.

Then, obviously, R1 = 90K, R2 = 45K, R3 = 22.5K 
and Rp0 = 1/(1/9 - 1/90 - 1/45 -1/22.5) = 30K

You can scale the resistor values up or down together, the absolute values were predetermined by the selection of the 90K feedback resistor.